# How to do CMake modules

Tags: c++, cmake

I try to learn c++ with cmake. I have done a project, and cmake runs, it compiles, it works, that is nice, ok. Now I started a new project in which I want to use some classes of the first one. I have tried to read some sourcecode and I have understand that I need to make a module that I can read from both the application. So this will be my repository:

```
/
/cmake
/modules/Network
/software/sw1
/software/sw2
```

both the projects `sw1` and `sw2` depends on the module `Netowrk`. In the folder cmake there has to be the `FindNetwork.cmake` file, and in `sw1`, `sw2` and `Network` there has to be the `CMakeList.txt` .

But.. I messed up with `include_directories` and other cmake obscurities..

Can someone point me out to a nice overview how to easily organize a repository with softwares that depend on common modules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This link](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/examples.html) will provide some examples for you.

In terms of how you are looking at the project/infrastructure then it's best to not confuse things too much. So here is a couple of points to get you started (I hope)

- In c++ a module is a library (so refer to your Network module as a
  library)
- To include a library you need to link it **and**  also      make the
  header files available.

In cmake this is two commands `target_link_libraries` and `include_directories`  respectively.

With that in mind the project structure could be

```
/Network/include (api here)
/Network/src
/sw1/src
/sw2/src
```

with an example base CmakeLists.txt file for you: (place in root dir of project)

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.7) // your choice
project(myproject) // change name 
add_subdirectory(Network)
add_subdirectory(sw1)
add_subdirectory(sw2)
```

in the Network Directory you would have this

```
add_library(Network net1.cc net2.cc etc.)
```

In the sw1 dir

```
include_dirs(${MYPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Network/include)
link_directories(${MYPROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Network)
add_executable (sw1prog sw1.cc sw11.cc etc.)
target_link_libraries (sw1prog Network)
```

In the sw2 dir

```
include_dirs(${MYPROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/Network/include)
link_directories(${MYPROJECT_BINARY_DIR}/Network)
add_executable (sw2prog sw2.cc sw21.cc etc.)
target_link_libraries (sw2prog Network)
```

This is a very simplified version of what you may require, it removes the need for a FindXXModule.cmake file to be created and refers to the library you create implicitly. I think this is the best mechanism for you, if you did want to create a FindXXModule.cmake then I would suggest it's when you actually install your libs to the machine and wish others to be able to find it, either that or have a mechanism for multiple projects to link to each other libraries.

I hope this is a little useful, please bear in mind the [cmake site](http://www.cmake.org) has some examples and `cmake --help` is your friend.

Comment: i thought it would be nice to have a FindXModule.cmake for abstract a little bit the library and have a way to easily create a new sw3 and just say: `use Network`, use `Database` and have a nice "plugin" system but your way seem simple too

Comment: You can achieve that by making an install path and having your system install to that path. The projects you then want to use the Network etc. would run a FindXModule.cmake. So really it's two separate issues, at least in my mind :-)

Comment: thank you very much. it work. i have tried to complicated it a little bit but more problems have raised now and I have done another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17264037/cmake-for-a-build-a-simple-framework